# How do I find out which component is failing?

Tags: hardware-failure

I have a computer tower which fails randomly. To be more specific:

- In random intervals (sometimes twice a day, sometimes not for two or three weeks) the computer will randomly crash.
- On Windows, it's a bluescreen with a reboot
- On Linux, it's a 5-10s hang and then a reboot
- The crash is not preceded by a certain action, as it's sometimes during high activity (number crunching, compiling, games), sometimes when it's just on the Desktop without background activity and I am not even in the room
- The crash is not connected to the operating system, as it happens on Linux and Windows
- The crash ist not connected to the hard drives, as it happens on three different ones
- The crash is not connected to temperatures, as I monitored it and CPU and GPU did not exceed 40°C
- If it's of interest: There's an Intel i5 in there, an EVGA GeForce GTX980 and 32GB RAM, Drivers up-to-date

It's rather annoying and I'd like to get it stable without switching out one component after the other until I find the faulty one, so my question:

1. How do I find out in Windows 7 or Ubuntu Logs which exact component the problem is?
2. What are my options of resolving this problem in case the logs do not help?

---

Update:
As suggested I ran memtest86, which came out clean without errors.
As for Reviewing the BlueScreen, the information provided there is notoriously unhelpful, just some Hex-Codes and such nonsense.

Comment: I would download and run a tool that checks RAM for errors. I had two occasions when bad RAM caused random BSODs (http://www.memtest.org/)

Comment: I would remove the graphics card and try just in case that's the one causing the problem.

Comment: I am going to tun memtest in a few minutes, removing the graphics card is a problem, as sometimes the problem doesn't occur for weeks. How would I know it woks?

Comment: Disable the automatic reboots in Windows and Linux.  Then you can review the DSOD/panic screen

Comment: BlueScreens are notoriously unhelpful and the information provided does not help in any way.

Comment: memtest86 passed without errors